# How to load a gallery into Fancybox with Title that does not change?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

So, basically, I am playing with Fancy box, and basically, just want a title to remain the same for all images in a gallery that get loaded.  Yes, I can just keep this as title for all images, however, when changing between images, the title fades in and out like the image does.  Basically, I don't want the title fading here, I just want the image fading.  Because the Title is always the same.

Here is a fiddle that shows my current problem here with the Title of a Fancybox image gallery:

http://jsfiddle.net/cce18389/3/

On all images the title will never change.  As the title depicts the Image Gallery Name (for now it's just filled with dummy content).

I have thought of how to possibly include HTML also within a fancybox 2.1 Gallery of images, however, I can not do this properly either, looking at this link here:  http://jsfiddle.net/svsdx/ which adds content to a div instead, not a photo gallery of images as I would like to do.

Here is the code as I have it now:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
var galleryTitle = $('#galleryTitleHTML').html();

    $('a.photogallery').fancybox({
        wrapCSS: 'fancy-gallery',
        openEffect: 'fade',
        closeEffect: 'fade',
        title: galleryTitle,
        tpl : {
            wrap : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div>'
        },
        helpers : {
            overlay: {
                css: {'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)' }
            },
            title: {
                type: 'outside',
                position: 'top'
            },
            thumbs : {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    });

    $('.open-photo-gallery').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var galleryImagesTotal = $('a.photogallery').length,
            eqToLoad = Math.abs(Math.floor(galleryImagesTotal / 2));

        $('a.photogallery:eq(' + eqToLoad + ')').click();
    });
});
```

Basically, I would like to pull in a div from the page and place that content above the images.  Only way I can see doing this is with the Title, but the title fades as the images fade.  Just want to get rid of this fading on the title.

Also, I would like the Gallery Title to fill the entire width of the top area, instead of changing to the width of the proportional image.

Anyway to do this?

Comment: can't post this an answer, one way to achieve is remove the prev and next effect ` nextEffect: "none", prevEffect: "none",` the title  will not disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/cce18389/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I see you could do this is appending the `title` to the fancybox *overlay* instead. You may need to set some styles for the `title` like :

```
.galleryTitle{
    z-index: 9000;
    color: #fff;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 5px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then in your fancybox code you need to add at least the following:

1). A flag to validate if the `title` has been already appended to the fancybox overlay

```
var addedTitle = false;
```

2). A `beforeShow` callback to append the `title` **if** this hasn't been appended yet (this prevents the `title` to be appended multiple times while browsing the gallery)

```
beforeShow: function () {
    if (!addedTitle) {
        $(".fancybox-overlay").append(galleryTitle)
        addedTitle = true;
    }
}
```

3). An `afterClose` callback to reset the value of the flag

```
afterClose: function () {
    addedTitle = false;
}
```

4). A fancybox `margin` option to make room for the `title` above (this may need to be adjusted to fit your needs)

```
margin: [80, 20, 20, 20] // [top, right, bottom, left]
```

**Note**: yes, you need to set all margins.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ucv9ev6m/)**

PS. Notice that in order to trigger the gallery you don't need to make a whole bunch of math calculations. Selecting the first item using the `.eq()` method would be enough :

```
$('.open-photo-gallery').click(function () {
    $('a.photogallery').eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your answer.  I decided to go with this approach, however, instead of adding margins, I simply used the title property, added in the `title`, and within the next child set `visibility: hidden`, and grabbed the next child after that for `prepending`, that way the space at the top remains consistent with whatever content is on the `title` and no margins need to be set at all.